# Calculating the difference between two Java calendars

Tags: java, java-time

I was trying to get the time in seconds from the difference of two calendars, and know if the result is more than one day(86400secs). The problem is that sometimes I obtain big negative values.

```
private long calcValidityDuration(XMLGregorianCalendar greg, XMLGregorianCalendar gregStart) {


        int minEnd = greg.getMinute();
        int minStart = gregStart.getMinute();
        int hourStart = gregStart.getHour();
        int hourEnd = greg.getHour();
        int dayEnd = greg.getDay();
        int dayStart = gregStart.getDay();
        int monthStart = gregStart.getMonth();
        int monthEnd = greg.getMonth();
        int yearStart = gregStart.getYear();
        int yearEnd = greg.getYear();

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(yearEnd, monthEnd - 1, dayEnd, hourEnd, minEnd);
        Calendar calStart = new GregorianCalendar();
        calStart.set(yearStart, monthStart - 1, dayStart, hourStart, minStart);
        long toRet = (((cal.getTimeInMillis()) - (calStart.getTimeInMillis())) / 1000);
        if(toRet >= 86400){
            return 86400;
        }else{
            return toRet;
        }
}
```

Here some of problematic dates:

Start date: 30/09/16 07
End date: 29/09/16 16

Start date: 29/09/16 16
End date: 29/09/16 16

Start date: 30/09/16 08
End date: 29/09/16 16

Start date: 29/09/16 16
End date: 21/11/14 19

Start date: 29/09/16 16
End date: 20/03/14 13

Comment: Can you give us an example of inputs that give you big negative values?

Comment: Also, I don't know whether this is significant for your use case; but when daylight savings starts and ends, you get days that are NOT 86400 seconds.

Comment: Please provide the example of the error in a way that we can run them - and that you have run them (the error may be there). Don't expect us to find a way to input those dates into your algorithm.

Comment: Are you obligated to use the obsolete calendar API?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static long getDistanceDay(Calendar one,Calendar two) {

    long time1 = one.getTimeMillis();
    long time2 = two.getTImeMillis();
    long time;

    if(time1 > time2) {
        time = time-time2;
    }
    else {
        time = time2 - time1;
    }
    return time/(1000*60*60*24)
}
```